RabbitMQ - How to connect RabbitMQ which is installed on other server (PC)
I want to connect RabbitMQ server which is installed on our other host machine [IP - 192.168.0.115]. and it runs locally on "localhost:15672" and i am trying to connect using my C# code.
This is my code to connect RabbitMQ from my local machine which is also connected in a same intranet environment.
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = "192.168.0.115",
                    UserName = "guest",         
                    Password = "guest",        
                    Port = 15672,                     
                                                       
                };

by using this code i am getting an exception of "Server not reachable".
if there is any server setting or firewall setting.
please guide me for this issue.

Have you try telnet to the ip address to check if you can reach the host?
Run the command telnet 192.168.0.115 5672 from your local machine. If the connection is successful, you should see a response indicating that the port is open.
The port you are using should be 5672 not 15672

the actual exception message is "RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'"

I believe the problem is in the port used.
The port you are using, 15672, is the default port for the rabbitmq management console.
For publisher or consumer connections, the default port is port 5672, using the AMQP protocol.
There may be some blocking between the servers. To test this, you can use the following command: telnet 192.168.0.115 5672
There is a topic explaining about RabbitMQ ports: What ports does RabbitMQ use?
